# Module content type not removed after uninstall

Tags: 7, nodes

My module adds content types by implementing `hook_node_info`. After *disabling* and **uninstalling** the module, the content type is still in the database and is merely marked as *disabled*.

*NOTE:* I also add create and instantiate custom fields for the created content type.

Since according to [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/73810/19626) content types created in `hook_node_info` are deleted automatically, is my problem a sign if DB inconsistency or am I doing something else wrong.

**Code:**

```
function test_core_node_info() {
    // Name of the proper localization function
    $t = get_t ();
    // Adding author
    return array (
            'test' => array (
                    'name' => $t ( 'Test' ),
                    'base' => 'test_module',
                    'description' => $t ( 'Test' ),
                    'title_label' => $t ( 'Title' ),
                    'locked' => TRUE 
            ) 
    );
}
```

**-- EDIT --**

I mentioned **removing** instead of **uninstalling**. This is corrected now.

Comment: did you implement hook Uninstall?

Comment: Yes. But in `hook_uninstall` I just remove the custom taxonomy vocabularies I added during the installation.

Answer (score 2):

You shall have to *uninstall* the module to get the type deleted automatically.  Just disabling it will not remove anything.  Deleting the module after disabling it - *without* uninstalling it first - is *not* a good idea.

After disabling the module, click on the “uninstall” tab at the top of the modules page and check the module you want to uninstall, then click the "Uninstall" button.

Comment: May bad: I meant "uninstalling" by removing not just deleting the folder!